# Solace JMS egress flows are not killed when using jmsTemplate receive in tests

Tags: jms, spring-integration, spring-jms, solace

I'm using CachingConnectionFactory to create JmsTemplate in a similar way:

```
@Bean
public JmsTemplate replyJmsTemplate() {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
    jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(...<CachingConnectionFactory>...);
    jmsTemplate.setDeliveryPersistent(...);
    jmsTemplate.setExcplicitQosEnabled();
    jmsTemplate.setTimeToLive(...);
}
```

than I call receiveSelected in my test classes:

```
replyJmsTemplate.receiveSelected(...);
```

I'm doing it in each of my test class. When I get expected message, my test is finished and I want current egress flow (to queue) to be closed. But it isn't. I execute all my test classes sequentialy (about 70 classes) so I have 70 egress flows active. All egress flows are released after all tests are finished. As a result sometimes I reach max egress flow which is set to 100 on my server. My question is how to close the egress flow after each test is executed? I guess I can manually close session in test but I cannot retrieve session from jmsTemplate.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are mentioning `JmsTemplate` as a `@Bean`, I can guess that you use Spring Testing Framework in your JUnit tests. For that purpose you should consider to close `ApplicaitonContext` after each test class. The `@DirtiesContext` comes to the help:

```
 * Test annotation which indicates that the
 * {@link org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext ApplicationContext}
 * associated with a test is <em>dirty</em> and should therefore be closed
 * and removed from the context cache.
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#dirtiescontext

Answer (score 2):

If each class has its own Spring `@Configuration`, add `@DirtiesContext` to each test class - it will close the test application context, destroying the connection factory.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I just used SingleConnectionFactory so that each session is killed after each test case is finished.